# how to get multiple arguments from option in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

```
#parse options
while getopts ":d:b:n:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    d)
          DIRS+=("$OPTARG")
          echo $DIRS
          ;;
    b)
          PATHBACKUP=$OPTARG
          echo $PATHBACKUP
          ;;
    n)
          FNAME=$OPTARG
          echo $FNAME
          ;;
    :)
          echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
          error
          exit 1
          ;;
  esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
```

This is my code I am trying to store every argument after -d to $DIRS
However, when I echo $DIRS I only get the first argument

Example:

```
/.script -d /dev /home/work -b /backup
echo $DIRS
echo $PATHBACKUP
> /dev
> /backup
```

Comment: It is an array, use: `echo "${DIRS[@]}"`

Comment: `/.script -d /dev -d /home/work -b /backup` multiple `-d`

Comment: @anubhava i still only get the first argument wether I do "${DIRS[@]}" or echo ${DIRS[*]}

Comment: the usage method should be only one -d.. unfortunatly

Comment: The syntax you're trying to support is nonstandard, so none of the standard option-parsing tools (`getopts`, `getopt`, etc) will work. You  will need to do the parsing "by hand".

Comment: @TD: Can you make it: `./script -d '/dev /home/work' -b /backup` ?

Comment: Use simple logical inference: You use **one** single `-d` when **calling** your script. In your script, each `-d` causes one argument appended to the `DIRS` array, as we can see from your code. Therefore, the array in the end has exactly as many elements as you had `-d` in the invocation. Therefore, `DIRS` must have 1 element in your example.

Comment: @anubhava: Not a good idea. You would have to apply word splitting to the argument afterwards, which breaks if you want to pass directory names which contain a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `-d`s

```
./script -d /dev -d /home/work -b /backup
```

otherwise, the first non-option (i.e. `/home/work`) would stop `getopts` option processing and `-b` won't be considered.

The other alternative would be to use some delimiter like `,` and parse it yourself

```
./script -d /dev,/home/work -b /backup
```

Comment: As per the assignment i am not allowed to alter his usage of -d /dev /home. Apparently I somehow loop through the $@ and add it to the DIRS but I cannot find the exact solution as when I do this, it adds every argument of the command line